# Blackberry Web Works - Data Storage

Tags: blackberry

am using http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/ to store data in my application. Lawnchair doesn't work in Blackberry Web Works. What framework can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using either the [HTML5 localStorage API](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#localstorage) or the [WebSQL Database](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#async_transactions).

If you're developing for BB OS 5, you'll need to add [html5_init.js](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20820/Using_HTML5_code_on_BB_devices_50_1238587_11.jsp) to your project and pages, since Webworks on BBOS 5 uses Google Gears instead of HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Blackberry persistant storage currently in the lawnchair adapters list that you might want to check out under
[adapters](https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair/tree/master/src/adapters).

Answer (score 0):

With JSON is easy, I have this tuturial: (but It's in portuguese) http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3627/html5-local-storage-com-json.aspx